# Reordering Initial Migration operations

Tags: python, django, migration, makemigrations

Every time I try to `migrate` my initial migration, right after `makemigrations`, I get errors like :

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InvalidBasesError: Cannot resolve bases for [<ModelState: 'Project.Class'>]
This can happen if you are inheriting models from an app with migrations (e.g. contrib.auth)
```

The reason I think this happens is because the order of model `operations` in the `0001_initial.py` migration is incorrect. Operations with classes which inherit from others are added before their parents'. After I reorder the operations, it works: `Process finished with exit code 0`. Cool! But how do I make `makemigrations` work without doing this every time?

Thanks!

ps. I tried reordering the import order of my models in the model's `__init__.py` but it didn't work.

Comment: Take a look if you are inheriting from a class in your model from an app that's not added to INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: The classes I get the error for are in the same app. :/

Comment: Ah, actually no - I inherit from other apps but I've checked and they're in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Do you have some custom migration maybe? If you are using a control version try deleting all the migrations and create them again, this is a hardcoded way to see if your old migrations have errors. It's a little difficult to tell you what could be wrong without to be seeing the project :(

Comment: I'm not aware of having any customisation. It's just the auto-generated initial migration. And yes, I delete all migrations before retrying this process. :/ Thanks anyway :))

Comment: Can you update with your models please.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example? Or the complete code base? Otherwise it is hard to help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have ***several apps in*** your ***Django project*** and *in models of one app models of another app are referenced* - this may result in such conflict.

It is recommended to ***create migrations for each app separately*** and reference another app migration as a dependency in referencing migration file.

```
python manage.py makemigrations app-one
python manage.py makemigrations app-two

# example of referencing dependent migration,
# so app-two 0001 migrations runs after app-one 0001 migration
# app-two/migrations/0001-initial.py

dependencies = [("app-one", "0001-init.py")]
```